# iText7 - Unable to add nested SVG using convertToImage

Tags: pdf, svg, itext7

I am unable to add nested svg(svg having another svg inside them) using `convertToImage(InputStream stream, PdfDocument document)` of iText.

Error log shows something like this -
`c.i.s.r.r.ResourceResolver               : Unable to retrieve image with data URI data:image&#x2F;svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyiusaPijhd78KJGKGKuuis79sgdf.........long string`

Kindly let me know how can we solve this. TIA.

Comment: Hi, can you attach the full logs and sample to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.